# NVD3 Sunburst Zooming into Wrong Section

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, nvd3.js, sunburst-diagram

When creating a sunburst chart with NVD3 (version 1.8.1) and D3 (version 3.5.8), I find that when I click on some lowest-level slices, it zooms into the incorrect section of the graph:

```
nv.addGraph(function () {
chart = nv.models.sunburstChart();
chart.color(d3.scale.category10());
d3.select("#test1")
    .datum(getData())
    .call(chart);
nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
return chart;
});
```

For instance, in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bradmarxmoosepi/2yk3qjhn/), when clicking on "Pug" it zooms to "Sparrow", but all other transitions seem to be working.

I have been unable to find the cause of this, as the x scale does seem to change domain to the correct values.

Additionally, the JSON data seems alright.

How would I correct for this?

Comment: Your fiddle seems to work for me. Clicking on "Pug" correctly zooms in on "Pug".

Comment: Your fiddle works well on FF but on chrome clicking on "Pug"  zooms to "Sparrow". Seems like the nvd3 library has an issue... however if you reduce the data to what is required it wrks well https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/nLt6nmv9/2/

Comment: As an addition to my first comment, for me Chrome 46, IE 11 and FF 41 are all doing fine. @Cyril

Comment: Hmm i am using chrome(Version 46.0.2490.80 (64-bit)) installed on ubuntu and i am able to recreate the issue :(

Comment: @Cyril I am running almost the same version Version 46.0.2490.86 m on a Win 8. However, the JSFiddle as it is linked to didn't work complaining about mixed content. I had to adjust either the JSFiddle from HTTPS to HTTP or the loading of D3 to HTTPS. As expected, both ways won't change the behaviour of the code.

Comment: @altocumulus sorry about the mixed content error. I was loading the d3 library from cdnjs but it was over HTTP.  I have updated the JSFiddle to correct for this.

Comment: @Cyril I can confirm that it is not working with Google Chrome Version 46.0.2490.86 (64-bit) installed under Linux Mint.  But it does work in Firefox 42.0 for Linux Mint.

Comment: Yea true the issue is more about Linux Google chrome @altocumulus yeah i did the https change.

Comment: @bradley Can you reduce the data set to relevant nodes as shown in my fiddle above in that case the error is gone. try that..

Comment: @Cyril Thanks for that, yes, I had noticed that if only those nodes are used in the data, then the problem goes away (a colleague also tried removing the larger nodes at random, sometimes the problem persisted and sometimes it remained).  However, the data in the current form (including all the nodes called "node") is how we would need it, but we have simply obfuscated all the names.